# Repository for the Facebook GAE sample not found

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

Could someone give a valid link for the Facebook app for Google App Engine "Run with friends" please, because [the](https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends/zipball/master) link given in the Facebook documentation is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it at https://github.com/fbsamples/runwithfriends/zipball/master.

All samples can be found at https://github.com/fbsamples/